# Setting watchpoint for multithreaded applications with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb, x86

**gdb** manual says the following.

*Warning: In multi-threaded programs, software watchpoints have only limited usefulness. If gdb creates a software watchpoint, it can only watch the value of an expression in a single thread. If you are confident that the expression can only change due to the current thread's activity (and if you are also confident that no other thread can become current), then you can use software watchpoints as usual. However, gdb may not notice when a non-current thread's activity changes the expression. (Hardware watchpoints, in contrast, watch an expression in all threads.)*

So, how can I use watchpoint with multiple threads using gdb, such that change to the watched variable from any thread is seen by gdb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, software watchpoints are really costly. You could use a hardware watchpoint, if you are watching a scalar data whose address is well defined, something like

```
  p &myvar
  $1 = (int*) 0x1234556
  watch *(int*) 0x1234556
```

This is relevant only for simple scalar data (single pointer, single integer, single byte...)

Comment: So how do I tell gdb to use a hardware watchpoint instead of a software one?

Comment: It is gdb who choose how it is implementing a watchpoint. Hardware watchpoints are possible only on very few scalar (fixed) addresses.

Comment: Make sure your gdb can actually use hw watchpoints: `(gdb) show can-use-hw-watchpoints`.

Comment: But does it work for multithreaded apps? I mean change of the variable by any thread can be seen by gdb?

Comment: I believe that yes. Hardware watchpoint are managed by hardware registers, and each core should have them.